# Patching module attributes when importing from file location

Tags: python, import, python-import, monkeypatching

Consider the three modules `a.py`, `b.py`, and `main.py`. They could each be in an arbitrary location, but for the sake of the example they will all be in the same directory.

Module `a` loads `b` by specifying its path with `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location`, and `main` does the same with `a`.

```py
# b.py
eggs = 42
```

```py
# a.py
import importlib.util
import os

B_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'b.py')  # could be an arbitrary path
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('b', B_PATH)
b = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(b)


spam = "ham"
print(f"{__name__} says {b.eggs=}")
```

```py
# main.py
import importlib.util
import os

A_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'a.py')  # could be an arbitrary path
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a', A_PATH)
a = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(a)


print(f"{__name__} says {a.spam=}")
```

When we run `main.py`:

```
$ python main.py
a says b.eggs=42
__main__ says a.spam='ham'
```

How can I patch `b.eggs` from `main.py` so that `a.py` sees the patched value?
Loading `b` from its file location and patching `b.eggs` before loading `a` doesn't work:

```py
# main.py v2
import importlib.util
import os

B_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'b.py')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('b', B_PATH)
b = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(b)

b.eggs = "patched"

A_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'a.py')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a', A_PATH)
a = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(a)


print(f"{__name__} says {a.spam=}")
print(f"{__name__} says {b.eggs=}")
```

```
$ python main.py
a says b.eggs=42
__main__ says a.spam='ham'
__main__ says b.eggs='patched'
```

How can I do this without patching the actual source code of `b`?

---

(Note that in this example, since all modules are in the same directory, importing from the file path is dumb, since it could be done with an `import` statement, but this is just to make a minimal working example. In my real case, my modules are in different directories and I can't modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, so I do it like this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing modules from source as shown doesn't check or update `sys.modules`, since it doesn't use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__). The [Language Reference says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system):

> A direct call to `__import__()` [...]
>   certain side-effects may occur, such as the importing of parent packages, and the updating of various caches (**including sys.modules**), [...]

Thus, for both `a` and `main` to see the same module object, we need to manually check and update `sys.modules`. Thus, to load modules from their path we could use this function:

```py
import sys, types

def load_from_path(name: str, path: str) -> types.ModuleType:
    if name not in sys.modules:
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, path)
        mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
        sys.modules[name] = mod
    return sys.modules[name]
```

Thus the example above becomes (assume `load_from_path` is defined in all modules):

```py
# b.py
eggs = 42
```

```py
# a.py
import importlib.util
import os

B_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'b.py')
b = load_from_path('b', B_PATH)


spam = "ham"
print(f"{__name__} says {b.eggs=}")
```

```py
# main.py
import importlib.util
import os

A_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'a.py')
B_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'b.py')

b = load_from_path('b', B_PATH)
b.eggs = "patched"
a = load_from_path('a', A_PATH)


print(f"{__name__} says {a.spam=}")
print(f"{__name__} says {b.eggs=}")
```

The output is:

```
a says b.eggs='patched'
__main__ says a.spam='ham'
__main__ says b.eggs='patched'
```